# Jmeter Embeded resources call

Tags: jmeter, resources

Compare a call of an URL with the option "Retrieve all embeded resourcees" to a call of the same URL followed by the explicit call of all the embeded resources.

Hello

I have two jmeter scripts that are basically identical (should be at least).

The first one is the call of a simple URL with the "Retrieve All Enbedded Resources" option checked (Parllaled dowmload set to 6).
The second one is a simple call of the same URL with the "embeded resources" option unchecked, followed by the call of all the embeded resources (20) through individual http requests.

Big surprise, the second option that I expected to be much slower is in fact much faster. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

When you run individual HTTP requests JMeter executes them sequentially and real browsers do it in parallel.

You shouldn't be comparing JMeter to a differently configured JMeter, you should compare JMeter to a real browser and do you best to ensure that [JMeter is configured to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser).

I can think of 2 options:

1. JMeter's DOM parser extracts resources URLs very slowly due to some specifics in your server response [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). In this case you should raise [an issue](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) in JMeter project and provide steps to reproduce and expected outcome.
2. Your server is not very good in handling parallel requests. Try putting those "individual" resource calls under the [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) and see how it does.

If you will be handling embedded resources manually you will need to take care of [Caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching), basically replicate the functionality of the [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager).